# Complex FQL Filter Question - Intersection of a greater than and equals to

Tags: faunadb

1. What is the best most efficient way to do this in FaunaDB?

```
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE sal >= 2000 AND deptno = 10
```

2.Can #1 be done using the intersection() function?

3. If you wanted to the below query how would it accomplished with FQL?

```
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE (sal >= 2000 OR sal < 500) AND deptno = 10
```

4. What about this query in FQL?

```
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE (sal >= 2000 OR sal < 500) AND deptno = 10 AND age > 21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. What is the best most efficient way to do this in FaunaDB?

That query can be done using **Range** function assuming you have the following index:

```
> CreateIndex({
  name: "sal_by_deptno",
  source: Collection("emp"),
  terms: [ { field: ['data', 'deptno'] } ],
  values: [ { field: ['data', 'sal'] }, { field: 'ref' } ]
})
```

you can do the query like this:

```
> Paginate(Range(Match(Index("sal_by_deptno"), 10), [2000], []))
{
  data: [
    [ 2000, Ref(Collection("emp"), "260259607265411603") ],
    [ 3000, Ref(Collection("emp"), "260259610695303699") ]
  ]
}
```

> 2. Can #1 be done using the intersection() function?

**Intersection** (and other set functions) only works if all operands have the same format, so I don't think it will be useful in that context.

> 3. If you wanted to the below query how would it accomplished with FQL?

```
Paginate(
  Union(
    Range(Match(Index("sal_by_deptno"), 10), [2000], []),
    Range(Match(Index("sal_by_deptno"), 10), [], [499.99])
  )
)
```

**Or** is equivalent to an union, so this is the function you should use in that context. Bear in mind that **Range** function is inclusive, so to simulate < operator I had to use a value less than 500

> 4. What about this query in FQL?

That one you would need a second index and then use **Join** function

```
CreateIndex({
  name: "age_by_ref",
  source: Collection("emp"),
  terms: [{field: 'ref'}],
  values: [{field: ['data', 'age']}, {field: 'ref'}]
})
```

Then query with this:

```
Paginate(
  Join(
    Union(
      Range(Match(Index("sal_by_deptno"), 10), [2000], []),
      Range(Match(Index("sal_by_deptno"), 10), [], [499.99])
    ),
    Lambda((sal, ref) => Range(Match(Index("age_by_ref"), ref), [22], []))
  )
)
```

The above solutions isn't by any means the definitive solution, this is just one possible solution that popped up in my mind as I answer this question.